# Is there a neighbourhood known for second-hand bookshops/antiquaries in Prague?

Tags: shopping, languages, czech-republic, prague

I'll be in Prague soon for a couple of days and I want to go dictionary-hunting. Is there a neighbourhood known for second-hand bookshops/antiquaries in Prague?

Comment: "Ps. Můžete mi taky psát odpovědi česky" I don't think we can write our answers in Czech, this is an English site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Prague 1** contains the biggest number of antique stores, followed by **Prague 3**. Some of the biggest ones are:

1. [Antikvariat Kant](https://foursquare.com/v/antikvari%C3%A1t-kant/4eae6f3d30f855f5b3b6253f) in Prague 1
2. [Antikvariat Aurora](https://foursquare.com/v/knihkupectv%C3%AD-a-antikvari%C3%A1t-aurora/4d7f670ef635236af8897816) in Prague 1
3. [Prague Thrift Store](https://foursquare.com/v/prague-thrift-store/4f576321e4b03d89eba2dfc1) in Prague 3

Comment: @iyoossaev: If you're happy with an answer, rather than say "thanks" in a comment, you should click on "accept" - that's the big tick symbol near the vote up/down arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Prague 1 is definitely where you will find the highest number of antique shops in Prague, but there are also a number of shops in other parts of the city.

I recently wrote a walking route that includes one of my favorite antique shops in the city,so check it out if you want. You can also sing up and post walking routes for your city here to help other fellow travelers :D cheers!

http://www.routey.net/City/Prague/Route/256/Antique-Shop-Walking-Tour-in-Prague

Comment: Welcome to the site! We get a bit nervous about people using answers here to promote their own sites. I suppose the first paragraph is a stand-alone answer to the question, so it's just about OK. But it is a rather brief answer -- some more detail would be nice. Do have a look at our [tour] and [guidelines on promoting yourself](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Comment: @dejan nice link, but it'd be really great if you could include the key parts of the page here, in case the link ever goes down.